# Add Arguments to dartfmt in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, dartfmt

I am currently using vscode for flutter and dart development and wanted to increase line length from 80 to 120 characters (which can be achieved by `dartfmt -l 120`). However, there does not seem to be a way to directly set that in the VSCode Flutter and Dart Extension. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: 80 chars should be plenty, provided you refactor your code so that lines never have more than 10 levels of indent.  Are you already doing that?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz the main issue is the length of the class names. Some class names are extremely long, and needing to add a new line to fit it in 80 characters makes the code much less readable. For this reason, I would like to see if increasing the line length makes it more readable. However, I can not find such an option in vscode's dart extension, leading to asking this question.

Comment: And I would then ask "why are the class names so long?"

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Because multiple classes perform similar purposes but are different classes. Just like `RectangularRangeSliderValueIndicatorShape` though shorter than that. Just to clarify, this is not a question asking whether or not I should increase line length, but how to do it. I also like the 80 character line length in general, but in specific cases, 120 is more useful. That is why I am looking for a way to change it in VSCode's Extension settings, because it is possible with dartfmt. It adds convenience to do it on autosave without reverting the formatting.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz That class name is built into flutter, not the one that I am writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VS Code Dart extension (version 3.18.1 as of writing) provides a "Dart: Line Length" option (`dart.lineLength`).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that! It just have been because I was trying to edit it within the dart file specific settings instead of the general settings.