# Flutter/Dart: Ignore lines_longer_than_80_chars only for strings in vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

with the rule when a format the code it becomes like this:

```dart
 final regex = 
     r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$';
```

I want to keep like this when I format:

```dart
 final regex = r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is reformatted by the *formatter* (`dart format`), not by the linter.  [The Dart VS Code extension has settings for the Dart formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65728131/).

There is separately the [`lines_longer_than_80_chars`](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#lines_longer_than_80_chars) lint for cases where `dart format` cannot break up a line (such as with long string literals).  If you increase the line length for `dart format`, you likely will want to disable this lint.

There is no way to make `dart format` or `dart analyzer` apply these rules conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

in fact you can prevent that lint by making the String a block type by using `'''`.

ie

```dart
final regex = r'''^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$''';
```

however the formatting will still occur