# Why does formatting code in VS Code always return uglier code than I expected?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, format, code-formatting

I'm formatting code in VS Code. However, VS Code always returns uglier code than I expected.

Example:

My original code:

```
                                                    body: Padding(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(AppSizes.kDefaultPadding,),
                                                      …
                                                    ),
```

Expected code:

```
                                                    body: Padding(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                        AppSizes.kDefaultPadding,
                                                      ),
                                                      …
                                                    ),
```

Actual code:

```
                                                    body: Padding(
                                                      padding:
                                                          const EdgeInsets.all(
                                                        AppSizes
                                                            .kDefaultPadding,
                                                      ),
                                                      …
                                                    ),
```

The actual code is really ugly (in my opinion, not sure how others see it).

How can I get the expected code? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Most likely you're getting non-ideal formatting because your lines are too long.  Your code is indented *a lot*.  Either refactor it to reduce indentation (usually a good idea) or [configure `dart format` to use a longer maximum line length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65728131/).

Comment: Hi @jamesdlin thanks for your reply. You mean press "command" + "shift" + "P" and type "Dart: Line Length"?

Comment: You need to open setting 1st, then you can get dart line length(I think)

Comment: Hi @YeasinSheikh thanks for your reply. Can you take a screenshot? I don't quite understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jamesdlin commented, Open your setting and search for `dart line length`, increase the value

[image]

[image]

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [Dart & Flutter support for Visual Studio Code](https://dartcode.org/docs/settings/)