# Why does if break into multiple lines?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

Why does this if:

```
if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty || !value.contains('@'))
```

breaks into multiple lines upon save?:

```
if (value == null ||
value.trim().isEmpty ||
!value.contains('@')) {
   return 'Please enter a valid email address';
}
```

I would like to keep it on a single line, is that possible with Dart and Flutter? I am using Visual Studio Code

Comment: I would imagine it's a code formatting option in vs code.

Comment: Because that's how [dart format](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-format) works. It applies these [formatting rules](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/Formatting-Rules).

Comment: That `if` statement as written normally would *not* be split across multiple lines.  It *would* be split across multiple lines if it were sufficiently indented such that the line length exceeds 80 columns.  [You can increase the maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65728443/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior comes from [dart format](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-format), which applies certain [formatting rules](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/Formatting-Rules) to your code.

To disable auto-formatting upon saving files, [Open User Settings (JSON)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909052/13625293) and add this setting (check first if this setting is already existing in the file):

```json
{
    // ...
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false,
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you might want to increase the allowed characters for a single line. You can change the value for `dart.lineLength` to change the formatting behavior and as well set the [vertical ruler line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968499/vertical-rulers-in-visual-studio-code) to visually draw the limit line on your editor.

```json
{
    // ...
    "dart.lineLength": 80,
    "editor.rulers": [80],
}
```

---

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65728443/13625293

Comment: thank you, I had to add 120 on both dart.line length and also edit settings.json ad add editor rule 120. 80 is default I guess and it breaks the lines to early for me